# Why using OR changes the meaning of the statement?

Tags: python

Using this bit of code works as intended:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

good = sys.argv[1]
if 'good' in good:
    print good
else:
    print 'bad'
---
>>> ./script.py good
good
>>> ./script.py good123
good123
>>> ./script.py hi
bad
```

But when I add an `or` to the if statement, the script 'stops' to work the way I thought it would work.

```
if 'good' or 'GOOD' or 'Good' in good:
```

I get:

```
>>> ./script.py hello123
hello123
```

Why is that ?

Comment: Adding some parentheses: `if ('good') or ('GOOD') or ('Good' in good):`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding some brackets should help show what's being evaluated:

```
if 'good' or 'GOOD' or ('Good' in good):
```

The `in` has a higher precedence than `or`, and doesn't act as you expected. So the `or` will return the first truthy argument, which will always be `'good'`, and the `if` will always succeed and run the code block.

Comment: I thought of something as well, but mine seems a bit more 'costly' and less dynamic:    if 'scp' in scp or 'Scp' in scp or 'SCP' in scp:

Comment: Yes that would be the correct solution, you could alternatively use `str.lower` (although this would also accept `GoOd`) like this: `'good' in good.lower()`, or in general you could use a loop to iterate through all the possibilities.